# render events without overlapping in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using eventSources to render events in fullcalendar.

```
eventSources = [ {events: Array1, editable: overlap: false }, {events: Array2, overlap: false}];
```

Some times there are Array1 and Array2 have overlapping time schedules. But I want to give the priority to Array 1 events. If there is events in Array1 which has the same startTime or endTime in Array2 , I want to display only Array1 events. Even I use 'overlap:false' attribute, events are overlapping with each other. Can anyone help me with this.
Is there a way to override available events ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
    $(this).data('event', {
        title: $.trim($(this).text()),
        backgroundColor:$.trim($(this).css("background-color")), // use the element's text as the event title
        textColor:$.trim($(this).css("color")), // use the element's text as the event title
        stick: true,// maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method),
        overlap:true,
        durationEditable:true,
    });

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
    });

});
```

you have to add overlap option. It will restrict event overlapping.